# Is it correct to say "gamble on one's career"?

Tags: word-request

Someone changed from his longterm employer to another in a totally different and unfamiliar area.

Is it correct to say "he gambled on his career", "he gambled his career", "he made gambling in his career" or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Not the last one -- not unless he left a steady job as a plumber to play blackjack seven days a week.

Answer (score 2):

"He gambled his career" is the best choice, but it doesn't really stand alone. "He gambled his career" is always followed by "on," for example: "He gambled his career on the success of his new employer."

Answer (score 1):

Normally when we try something new that will have an uncertain outcome, we "*take* a gamble".

> His current occupation had no future opportunity, so he **took a gamble** by going into real estate. Hopefully he will still be able to pay his rent.